# Why is the order in the Setup so hard?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-orm2

I build an node express app based off the node-orm2 example project which is included in the library. I had an nasty 'bug' where my return value looked messed up.

An "User" has only one "Permission": `User.hasOne('permission', db.models.permission, {required: true, autoFetch: true});`
And a "Company" has one owner but this is reversed so a "User" has multiple "Companies". `Company.hasOne('user', db.models.user, { required: true, reverse: 'companies', autoFetch: true});`

### First setup:

```
function setup(db, cb) {
 require('./company')(orm, db);
 require('./user')(orm, db);
 require('./permission')(orm, db);

 return cb(null, db);
}
```

### Messed up result:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "username": "l.vanbuiten",
  "name": "Lex",
  "surname": "van Buiten",
  "age": "1992-05-13T22:00:00.000Z",
  "createdAt": "2015-12-21T23:25:04.000Z",
  "permission": {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "l.vanbuiten",
    "name": "Lex",
    "surname": "van Buiten",
    "age": "1992-05-13T22:00:00.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2015-12-21T23:25:04.000Z",
    "permission_id": 1
  },
  "companies": []
}
```

After swapping these setup rows things got as i wanted:

### How it should be:

```
function setup(db, cb) {
 require('./permission')(orm, db);
 require('./user')(orm, db);
 require('./company')(orm, db);

 return cb(null, db);
}
```

### Desired result

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "username": "l.vanbuiten",
  "name": "Lex",
  "surname": "van Buiten",
  "age": "1992-05-13T22:00:00.000Z",
  "createdAt": "2015-12-21T23:25:04.000Z",
  "permission": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "permission name"
  },
  "companies": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "company name",
      "description": "company description",
      "createdAt": "2015-12-21T23:25:25.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

### One example model:

```
var moment = require('moment');

module.exports = function (orm, db) {
var Company = db.define('company', {
    id:             {type: 'serial', key: true},
    name:           {type: 'text', required: true, unique: true},
    description:    {type: 'text', big: true},
    createdAt:  {type: 'date', required: true, time: true}
},
{
    cache: false,
    hooks: {
        beforeValidation: function () {
            this.createdAt = new Date();
        }
    },
    validations: {
        name: [
            orm.enforce.unique("Company already exist"),
            orm.enforce.ranges.length(1, undefined, "Company name cannot be empty"),
            orm.enforce.ranges.length(undefined, 50, "Company name is to long")
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        serialize: function () {
            return {
                id: this.id,
                name: this.name,
                description: this.description,
                createdAt: this.createdAt
            }
        }
    }
});
Company.hasOne('user', db.models.user, { required: true, reverse: 'companies', autoFetch: true});
};
```

How is it that the order differs so much?

Comment: Both `setup()`'s that you post are the same. Also, you should post at least one implementation of the files you're requiring.

Comment: @robertklep Thank you for your comment, i update the post with the right order of setup. As suggested i posted one of my classes, but in all honesty it doesn't differ that much with the Anontxt project on their GitHub repository: [link](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/tree/master/examples/anontxt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I don't have a lot of `node-orm2` experience)

It seems to me that the way you're setting up associations is causing your problems.

In your first setup, the order in which you define models and associations is as follows:

- create the `Company` model
- create the association between `Company` and `User` through `db.models.user` (which doesn't exist yet!)
- create the `User` model
- etc.

Instead, I think you have to wait until all models have been defined before you can create the associations:

```
function setup(db, cb) {
  // Create models.
  var Permission = require('./permission')(orm, db);
  var User       = require('./user')(orm, db);
  var Company    = require('./company')(orm, db);

  // Create associations.
  Company.hasOne('user', User, { required: true, reverse: 'companies', autoFetch: true});
  ...

  // Return.
  return cb(null, db);
}
```

(this also assumes that the exported function in each required model file returns the model, e.g. `return Company` at the end of `company.js`).

Comment: I took your suggestion into practice and it works like a charm. This way ordering doesn't matter for the models (and associations in this case). Thanks!